Metro Disconnected After Successful Install Android App React Native
Reload Functionality does not work.
Showing This Message.
Info Reloading connected app(s)...
warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
You see in this image build successfully done and app install in device but not launch automatically and reload not working.
React Native Version 0.75.2
I am Running this project with Metro
Project Running cmd:

npx react-native start --reset-cache
npx react-native run-android --mode=devDebug --appId=myAppPackage

info Opening app on Android...
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...

Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.5.0
Gradle: 8.8
Task :app:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
Task :app:generateAutolinkingPackageList UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:generateCodegenSchemaFromJavaScript SKIPPED
Task :app:generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema SKIPPED
Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:stripDevDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:validateSigningDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:writeDevDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:writeDevDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:packageDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:createDevDebugApkListingFileRedirect UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:installDevDebug
Installing APK 'app-dev-debug.apk' on 'Pixel 6 - 14' for :app:dev-debug
Installed on 1 device.


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.


You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.


For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 19s
355 actionable tasks: 25 executed, 330 up-to-date


info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
info Reloading connected app(s)...
warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.

What is the problem?
Is it metro problem? or react version problem?

try rebooting your machine

i have already tried this @hippoman

Don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Instead post a [mcve]. Format Gradle output as a [code block], not as a quote.

what are you using , simulator or real device?

@AbhishekKumarKushwaha I tried both, getting same issue.

@Robert ok, Thanks for your feedback. Next time I will take care of it. Thanks Again.

check for the space available , sometimes it happen when the system doesn't have enough space

@AbhishekKumarKushwaha I checked it. This is not space issue.

try npx react-native start after metro goes off or adb kill server / start server

@AbhishekKumarKushwaha Already Tried.

Again, please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data. Please [edit] to replace the images with text we can copy/paste.

You can try configuring metro bundle manually.
Steps:

Shake device to open Dev Menu,
Select "Configure Bundler"
Enter your system IP Address in prompt and Press "Apple Changes".

Note

Device and Mac System needs to be connected in the same network

